# Kendo master auto increment id showing in child grid when using clientTemplate of kendo UI Grid Hierarchy in C# MVC

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, client-templates

I was implemented kendo Grid Hierarchy in my list page. but when i list child item without client template then auto increment id of each item showing properly but when i use clientTemplate property of kendo grid in child grid to show auto increment id then only auto increment id of parent item was showing.
Example showing on bellow 
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy

Parent Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.OrderList)
                                        .Name("Grid")
                                        .Columns(columns =>
                                        {
                                            columns.Bound(p => p.OrderID).Width("50px").Sortable(false).Filterable(false).Title("<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll' onchange='SelectAll();'/>").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='orderselect_#=OrderID#' class='orderselect' value='#=OrderID#' onchange='chkOrUnchk(this)'/>");

                                        })
                                        .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
                                        //.Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
                                        .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple).Enabled(true))
                                        .Events(events => events.Change("Grid_OnRowSelect").DataBound("OrderGrid_OnDataBound").ColumnReorder("Grid_OnColumnReorder"))
                                        .Pageable(settings => settings.PageSizes(new int[] { 25, 50, 100, 500 }))
                                        .Sortable()
                                        .Scrollable(s => s.Virtual(false).Height("600px"))
                                        .Filterable()
                                        .ClientDetailTemplateId("childOrders")
                                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                                    //.Server().Model(model => model.Id(p => p.OrderID))
                                                    .Ajax()
                                                    .PageSize(Model.DefaultOrderPageSize)
                                                    .Read(read => read.Action("ManageOrderLoadForGridAjax", "Order").Data("OrderSearchParameter"))
                                        )
                                )

                                Child Grid
                                <script id="childOrders" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
                                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(new List<SMOrderNew>())
                                            .Name("grid_#=OrderID#") // template expression, to be evaluated in the master context
                                            .Columns(columns =>
                                            {
                                                // *i want child order number but return parent order number using client template*
                                                columns.Bound(p => p.OrderID).Width("50px").Sortable(false).Filterable(false).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='orderselect_#=OrderID#' class='orderselect' value='#=OrderID#' onchange='chkOrUnchk(this)'/>");
                                                columns.Bound(p => p.OrderNumber).Groupable(false).Width("200px").Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a #if(DisplayDistribution){# class='OrderHover'#}# data-id='#= OrderID #' href='javascript:void(0);' style='float:left;' onclick='OpenOrderDetailsPopup(\"#= OrderID #\", 0);'> #=OrderNumber# </a>");
                                                //columns.Bound(p => p.StoreName).Title("Store").Width(100).Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<div style='background:url(\"#=StoreImage_Icon#\") no-repeat left -2px; padding-left:20px;'>#=StoreName#</div>");
                                                columns.Bound(p => p.BuyerUserID).Width("200px").Title("Buyer User ID").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "white-space: nowrap;" });
                                            })
                                            .Events(events => events.Change("Grid_OnRowSelect").DataBound("OrderGrid_OnDataBound").ColumnReorder("Grid_OnColumnReorder"))
                                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                                .Ajax()
                                                .PageSize(100)
                                                .Read(read => read.Action("ManageChildOrderLoadForGridAjax", "Order", new { OrderId = "#=OrderID#" }))
                                            )
                                            //.ClientDetailTemplateId("attributeOption")
                                            .Pageable()
                                            .Sortable()
                                            .ToClientTemplate()
                                    )
                                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the issue and found the way the fix it. It's scope issue, the solution is that use the \#=OwnProperty\# escape symbol for the child's property value. the regular syntax #=Parent Property# is for the parent's property.

[grid-child-properties-in-child-template](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-child-properties-in-child-template)